# how to secure remote access RDP using CA standalone

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-server, rdp

this is for personal use, I have an OVH VM (windows server), I created a CA STANDALONE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PuiQ.png)

what I'm looking for is to secure the RDP access with certificate.

but the problem I dont see the certificate template.

could you help please ?

but the problem I dont see the certificate template.